# Turn API call forEach Loop into Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an API call with a `forEach` loop which I need to be finished before another function is called. It looks like this:

```
var getTypes = function() {
        var stations = [];

        stationservice.getCount('/stations')
        .then(succCB, errorCB);

        function succCB(data) {
            data.data.forEach(function(station) {
                stations.push({
                    id: station._id,
                })
            })
        };
        // This should only be called once the forEach Loop is done
        processStations(stations);
}
```

I can't find an understandable example of how I can make sure the `processStations()` gets called once the loop is done. How can I create a promise for this such that it does what I want to achieve?

Comment: put the code that needs to be done after the forEach loop **just after** the forEach loop, but inside `succCB` - otherwise asynchrony will bite you ... note: use array map function instead of pushing to a new array as an argument to processStations .... e.g. `processStations(data.data.map(station => ({id: sation._id})))`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, bad example in this case. I am still interested on how this can be achieved using promises, as I have other examples where this wouldn't work.

Comment: `how this can be achieved using promises` - you are using promises (the `.then` is the giveaway)

Comment: *bad example* - well, each case would result in a different answer - best you read up on some promise docs :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you use promises you have to chain everything that depends on that promise (or use `await` and `async` if your environment supports it):

```
function getTypes() {
  return stationservice.getCount('/stations')
    .then(function(data) {
      var stations = [];
      data.data.forEach(function(station) {
        stations.push({
          id: station._id,
        })
      })
      return stations;
    })
    .then(processStations);
}
```

And you should return the Promise chain from your `getTypes` at least if the `getTypes` should return something that depends on the `stationservice.getCount`.

Instead of the `forEach` you might want to use `map` because this is what you actually do:

```
function getTypes() {
  return stationservice.getCount('/stations')
    .then(function(data) {
      return data.data.map(function(station) {
        return {
          id: station._id,
        };
      })
    })
    .then(processStations);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "modern code" answer

```
var getTypes = function() {
    return stationservice.getCount('/stations')
    .then(data => data.data.map(({_id: id}) =>({id})))
    .then(processStations);
}
```

this is equal to

```
var getTypes = function getTypes() {
    return stationservice.getCount('/stations').then(function (data) {
        return data.data.map(function (_ref) {
            return { id: _ref._id };
        });
    }).then(processStations);
};
```

Though, since the map isn't asynchronous at all

```
const getTypes = () => stationservice.getCount('/stations').then(data => processStations(data.data.map(({_id: id}) =>({id}))));
```

is just fine - and in pre modern browser

```
var getTypes = function getTypes() {
    return stationservice.getCount('/stations').then(function (data) {
        return processStations(data.data.map(function (_ref) {
            return { id: _ref._id };
        }));
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Async library

```
async.forEach(data.data, function (item, callback){ 
    stations.push({
        id: item._id,
    })
    callback(); 
}, function(err) {
    processStations(stations);
});
```

Comment: Should be either `item.push` or `(id: item._id)` right?

Comment: using async.js with promises (and there are already promises in the question) is a recipe for disaster

Comment: Using Promises or the Async library will result in the same _problem_ both are async.  Your `function(err) { processStations(stations);}` would be that _same_  as using `.then` with Promises.